# C# Code generator that can speeds up the development of a DB driven software?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, code-generation

I'm new to c# and .net development. I'm looking for a C# code generator that can generate the code for CRUD operations and entity objects against tables in a database. It needs to be:

Support Oracle database;
The generated code must be simple and easy to use.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

- Entity Framework with an Oracle provider
- [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/361.html)
- [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/pages/requirements.aspx)
- [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) (like LINQ-to-SQL)

Comment: Think he was more after a code generator, rather than just some ORM tools

Comment: Most ORM tools function as a code generator... to distinguish between them we'd need more detail from the OP...

Comment: Sorry, I meant he was after a code generator for the objects too, not just the DAL

Comment: Thank you Marc, I'll check them out. Martin, I prefer a code generator that generates simple and easy to consume classes rather than complex ORMs

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) for generating code from Oracle. It should support generating the files to be used by frameworks such as [.netTiers](http://nettiers.com), [nHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a ORM tool. There are a number of ORM tools on the market, Some are open source projects while others are large scale commercial products.

Here's a list of .NET based ORMs that supports Oracle that I have heard/read/used:

DataObjects.Net

Nhibernate

SubSonic

Answer (score 0):

[MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com) is a popular code generator for data-access. I believe it has an oracle template(s):

Comment: Thank you very much JohoW, it looks powerful and best of all is that it's open source! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I definately agree that you should be looking at/for an ORM product. In addition to those already mentioned I would bring up Telerik's Open Access. It covers a good number of databases and integrates well to a number of other Microsoft technologies.

The down side is that it isn't free. But in my case our company purchased it in a package with controls. We needed to purchase a set of controls for a Silverlight project. I sold the boss on purchasing their suite as if we ever needed controls for either WPF or WinForms it would be paid for. They have a suite that contains controls for just about any .NET project along with their ORM and reporting.